# Why are links to resources a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits

In the past, I've had edits rejected because they add too much information or try to answer the original post, so I've been limiting myself to edits that add links to resources or samples. But, these edits sometimes get rejected as well! See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12937033, for instance. (Btw, the links are the documentation that the OP was asking for, not for a competing service as one reviewer thought.)

I've read related questions on Meta, where people suggested adding more comments on the edit itself. In this case, the original answer specifically mentioned other articles, so I mentioned that in my edit comment. In the future, should I add even more text, such as "linking to the articles mentioned in the answer"?

I'm close to being able to do edits without review, so should I be avoiding these kinds of edit entirely?  That would be unfortunate, as I'd like other users to see the links in the answer itself.

Comment: Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8801864. The OP had asked for video links, which could have been added as comment, but would be better as part of the answer.

Comment: Reviewers are fickle. In five upvotes you won't have to worry about this anymore.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: True, but I don't want to be doing edits that are in bad form.

Comment: Well, that's a good thought.

Comment: Side note: Vote to close is more appropriate for "give me link to tutorial" questions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Could you clarify?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft as covered in [Magisch's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/327581/477420) if question is off-topic it is better to act on question first (vote/flag to close, edit, comment) than improving answers that potentially will disappear with question. Additionally answering/improving answers to off-topic questions encourages more off-topic question to be asked in the first place - so really not good for SO overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the past, I've had edits rejected because they add too much
>   information or try to answer the original post, so I've been limiting
>   myself to edits that add links to resources or samples

Edits should not significantly change the contents of a post without the approval of the author (ask first). They're there mainly for fixing formatting issues, grammar, spelling, general formulation, or re-clarifying unclear points.

When you look at [the official guidance on edits from the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), you'll find this:

> Some common reasons to edit are:
>
> - to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
> - to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it
> - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages
> - to add related resources or hyperlinks

These are what you should mainly be doing. That being said, the reviewers in the SE queue can be notoriously fickle about approving links in edits. This often comes from the fact that any given reviewer does not know the substance of the post you're editing, so make it easier for them by writing a descriptive edit summary, like:

> Added some links to official ressources closely related to the problem at hand

Also make sure you always fix all of the issues with a post - not just add some links when other issues are present.

In general though, when you see a very clearly off topic question, like a question directly asking for tutorial recommendations, it would be better to vote to close (or flag to close, in your case) that question rather then edit it. Some questions that are closable are salvageable by edits, but some are also not.

> I'm close to being able to do edits without review, so should I be
>   avoiding these kinds of edit entirely? That would be unfortunate, as
>   I'd like other users to see the links in the answer itself.

Make sure you only add these links if you're confident that they enhance the answer in general, and are closely related to the problem at hand. Sometimes linking to general tutorials doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Links to official resources are sometimes OK. But adding links to third-party resources puts words into an answerer's mouth. Those should be comments.